# Not getting video tracks from iPhone users with safari

Tags: twilio, twilio-video

I have set up a group room with recording turned on and codec enforced to  H.264. The iPhone users are able to see others video, but others can’t see theirs.

```
 participant.tracks.forEach(publication => {
          console.log("test1", publication);
          if (publication.isSubscribed) { // THIS IS FALSE ALWAYS WHEN THE REMOTE PARTICIPANT USES AN IPHONE WITH SAFARI BROWSER
                const track = publication.track;
               document.getElementById('remote-media-div').appendChild(track.attach());
           }
 });
```

Comment: Are you enforcing h.264 codec yourself, and if so, how? Also, are you able to listen to the `room` object for `trackPublished` events rather than just getting the tracks from the participant?

Comment: Hi the problem was the link being sent to invite was http and https then it started working.

Comment: Ah, glad that's sorted!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To others facing the same problem, make sure your link is https and not http, even though we had ssl the code sending the meeting email was sending the link as http instead of https.